# Push replication on pypi repos

Tags: artifactory, pypi

I've been trying to setup push replication in pypi repos, however that does not seem to work. If I setup the remote to be a generic repo, then the files get pushed. Otherwise, if it's a pypi repo, then I get the following error:

```
Error while deploying item 'test:gcovr/3.2/gcovr-3.2-py2.7.egg on Url:http://artifactory/artifactory/api/pypi/testpypi ': Method Not Allowed [405]
```

When trying to replicate the test repo to testpypi. Am I doing something wrong here? I've tried suffixing with simple or even just a /. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following URL format when configuring the replication:

```
http://artifactory/artifactory/testpypi
```

Comment: Cool. That worked! Unfortunately event replication doesn't work when uploading eggs with setuptools, which I think is likely a bug.